# assigning variables in if statements c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, scope, variable-assignment, unassigned-variable

My problem is this: I am writing a console application for c# that involves user authentication. I have declared a User class and placed all existing users in a list. I have this block to see if the user's input matches an existing username in the logon sequence.

```
User CurrentUser;
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    if (UsernameLogonInput == users[i].Name)
    {
        nameExists = true;
        CurrentUser = users[i];
    }
}
```

That's all well and good, but later, I have this block, for signing in.

```
if (nameExists)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Password : ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == CurrentUser.Password)
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID. EC102");
        }
    } while (!isValid);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that visual studio is saying "use of an unassigned local variable" to `CurrentUser.Password` in the second block. I'm pretty sure this is because CurrentUser is assigned in an if statement, and I was wondering if there was any way to get around this problem of block scope.

Comment: Assign `CurrentUser` equal to `null`, and then check to see if it is null before you check it's `Password` property.

Comment: I dont know if this is an assignment for school, but this is an _awful_ way to authenticate users.  If this is for a personal project or for your job I strongly recommend you think of alternative solutions (or better yet, use existing authentication frameworks)

Comment: @maccettura is correct; this is really bad. One of the ways it is bad is: never do a user identification check *before* the password check. Get both the user identifier and the password at the same time, and then check to see if they are a valid pair, and then give the *same* error regardless of whether the user name or the password is bad. That way an attacker cannot determine whether a given name is a valid account or not by trying it with a dummy password.

Comment: Thankfully, I'm not doing this to be as secure as possible. I'm doing it to get a feel for the language, but I see now that this would definitely be a bad way to do it. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get around the problem by initializing the variable when you declare it, even if it's a null or empty value. For example:

```
User CurrentUser = null;
```

But when you have to do this, it might indicate that there is some better way to order your logic. For example, instead of all this:

```
User CurrentUser;
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    if (UsernameLogonInput == users[i].Name)
    {
        nameExists = true;
        CurrentUser = users[i];
    }
}
```

...you could just write this:

```
//using System.Linq;
User CurrentUser = users.SingleOrDefault( u => u.Name == UsernameLogonInput );
```

which will initialize the variable to either the matching user or null if none is found.

SingleOrDefault is an extension method from the System.Linq namespace. It accepts an expression as an argument, and will search the list and find any single record that matches, or default/null if there isn't a match. The argument is a lambda expression.

Comment: Note that if you do it this way, you don't have to keep track of `nameExists` at all. Either the current user is non-null, in which case the name existed, or the current user is null, in which case the name did not exist.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I fully understand the SingleOrDefault part, but that's good to know.